# How to make a background image fit in size of differnt screens?

Tags: html, css, background

I want to make a login page with background image on it. On top of background image I made a box, where I put login elements. Because of that I couldn't fit size of both elements in one screen. I was trying to fit size on diiferent phones, such as Iphone(all versions) and Android.
Here is HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: content: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
   <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
   <form>
       <span class="text-center">ヘルスケア</span>
   <div class="input-container">
       <input type="text" id ="userName" required=""/>
       <label>ユーザ名</label>     
   </div>
   <div class="input-container">       
       <input type="password" id ="password" required=""/>
       <label>パスワード</label>
   </div >
       <div class="center">
           <button onclick="login()" type="button" class="btn">ログイン</button>
       </div>
       <div class="center">
           <a id="reset" href="reset.html">パスワードを忘れた方はこちら</a>
       </div>
       <div class="regText">
           <p>アカウントを持ちでない場合はこちらから</p>
       </div>
       <div class="center">
           <a id ="register" href="login.html">アカウントを新規登録</a>
       </div>
</form> 
</div>
</body>
<footer>
   <div class="copyright"> © 2022 Copyright by Company Name. All Rights Reserved. </div>
</footer>
</html>
```

This is my CSS file:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,400i,700,700i&subset=greek-ext');
body{
    background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/6455924/pexels-photo-6455924.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-julia-larson-6455924.jpg&fm=jpg&_gl=1*pg770f*_ga*MTc4NzcyMDU0OS4xNjY3OTE4NjQz*_ga_8JE65Q40S6*MTY2NzkxODY0My4xLjEuMTY2NzkyMDUxOC4wLjAuMA..");
    background-position: center;
    background-origin: content-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height:100vh;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
.text-center{
    color:#fff; 
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size: 45px;
    margin: -50px 0 80px 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.box{
    position:absolute;
    width: 350px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5); 
    background-size: cover;
    border-radius:3px;
    padding:300px 300px;
}
.input-container{
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}
.input-container label{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#fff; 
    pointer-events:none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.input-container input{ 
  border:0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #555;  
  background:transparent;
  width:100%;
  padding:25px 0 0 0;
  font-size:24px;
  color:#fff;
}
.input-container input:focus{ 
 border:none;   
 outline:none;
 border-bottom:2px solid #e74c3c;   
}
.btn{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#e74c3c;
    outline: none;
    border: 0;
    padding:10px 135px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-top:50px;
    border-radius:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.input-container input:focus ~ label,
.input-container input:valid ~ label{
    top:-12px;
    font-size:12px;
}
a#reset{
    margin-top: 10px ;
    font-size: 16px;
    float: center;
    color: yellow;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
a#register{
    font-size: 16px;
    float: center;
    color: yellow;
    align-items: center;
}
.center {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  height: 40px;
}
.regText {
    margin: 50px 0 0 0; 
    color: #ffffff;   
}
p {
    display: block;
    margin-block-start: 0em;
    margin-block-end: 0em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are familiar with `grid` then, give `height: 100%` to your `div` and give `max-width: 100%` to your image and may be it's work perfectly for you.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .imgBox {
            display: grid;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .centerFit {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100vh;
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="imgBox">
    <img class="centerFit" src='pic.png'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```